# How to add a separator to Evaluate function in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that takes two columns from a Pivot Table, combines & copies the values and outputs the combined output into another table range. The only problem is that these values are combined together without any spaces or separators at all. I would like to add " - " between the values.

I've tried adding "- " between the Ranges and get "Type mismatch" errors no matter how I try to add it.

One of my tries:

```
r = wsCopy.Evaluate("=A5:A" & DefCopyLastRow & "- " & "& B5:B" & DefCopyLastRow)
```

Full original code:

```
Dim r

r = wsCopy.Evaluate("=A5:A" & DefCopyLastRow & "& B5:B" & DefCopyLastRow)
wsDest.Range("J" & DefDestLastRow).Resize(UBound(r, 1), 1).Value = r
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: @JvdV I'm still getting type mismatch error when adding multiple `"` to the separator

Comment: What do you want to do with an "&" in a range? `A5:A9& B5:B9` is not a valid range AFAIK

Comment: @PatrickHonorez the code works perfectly fine the way it is with that range. I just can't seem to add a separator in between the ranges
EDIT: In fact, the code DOESN'T work without the "&" before the B range...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need quotes and ampersands inside your formula string:

```
r = wsCopy.Evaluate("=A5:A" & DefCopyLastRow & "&"" - ""&B5:B" & DefCopyLastRow)
```